# How to write a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have just discovered that a LaTeX compilation could be launched from a makefile. I came to this from the need to generate a series of targets with some alterations of parameters.
I have the file at the bottom. How can I add other compilation jobs, with different optional parameters say. Said otherwise, how to change the name of the target file(s) when there is more than one?

```
MyFileNew.pdf : MyFile.tex
    pdflatex "\def\UseOption{nonumber,nographics,e} \input{MyFile.tex}"

#makefile
MyFile.pdf : MyFile.tex
    pdflatex "\def\UseOption{number,graphics,ef} \input{MyFile.tex}"\
    pdflatex "\def\UseOption{number,graphics,ef} \input{MyFile.tex}"

    @echo «Removing auxilliary LaTeX files resulting from compilation»
    @rm -f *.log *.aux *.dvi *.toc *.lot *.lof
#end of makefile
```

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. You already show you know how to add a new target, so where's the problem? For example, what make commands on the command line would you like to run (compared to `> make MyFileNew.pdf` and `make MyFile.pdf`).

Comment: Oh, just a tip: create a `clean` target to clean up the auxiliary files (`make clean`). You don't want to have that included with your normal target (log files can be really useful).

Comment: My concern is that I have read that the first line of a makefile should be like the one below #makefile. Is is possible to add in the middle of hte makefile a new line such as :                              MyFileNew.pdf : MyFile.tex (same source but a different target name?)

Comment: The actions have to be indented by a tab (expand to 4 or 8 spaces for presentation on SO).  The `MyFile.pdf` actions treat the two commands as part of one line. You probably want a semicolon before the backslash.  I cant see the difference between the two lines anyway.  You might also in due course use `make` macros to identify files, rather than writing the name out multiple times.

Comment: Show what you would type at the command line with multiple files.  Then it may be possible to adapt that to the `makefile`.

Comment: The two identical lines are meant to get a dual compilation (very often mandatory for the target document to have the internal references correct (list of figures, page numbers, etc) Admittedly the way I handle the dual compilation may not be professional.

Comment: Neglecting the dual compilation, I would like to write say                                      MyFile1.pdf : MyFile.tex
pdflatex "\def\UseOption{number,graphics,ef} \input{MyFile.tex}"        MyFile2.pdf : MyFile.tex
pdflatex "\def\UseOption{nonumber,nographics,f} \input{MyFile.tex}"

Comment: You can add new rules wherever you like.  If you are understanding what you read correctly, then what you read is wrong.  The ordering issue it was probably referring to is that the first target in the makefile (doesn't have be the first line!) is run by default when you type `make`.  If you want a different target `foo` you need to run `make foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works finally as expected (except for cleaning the auxilliary files).

## Makefile

```
.PHONY: all clean clean-all
all : TargetFile1.pdf TargetFile2.pdf

TargetFile1.pdf : MyFile.tex
    pdflatex --jobname=$(@:.pdf=) "\def\UseOption{number,nographics,e} \input{MyFile.tex}"

TargetFile2.pdf : MyFile.tex
    pdflatex --jobname=$(@:.pdf=) "\def\UseOption{number,nographics,ef} \input{MyFile.tex}"

clean :
    rm -f *.log *.aux *.dvi *.toc *.lof

clean-all : clean
    rm -fr *.pdf
# Makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for something like this?

```
pdflatex := pdflatex "\def\UseOption{$(options_$*)} \input{$<}"
cleanup := rm -f *.log *.aux *.dvi *.toc *.lot *.lof

options_MyFileNew := nonumber,nographics,e
options_MyFile := number,graphics,ef

MyFileNew.pdf MyFile.pdf: %.pdf: MyFile.tex
    $(pdflatex)
    $(pdflatex)
    $(cleanup)
```

This is basically just a refactoring of what you already have.

Comment: I am sensing that what you had in your question was a Makefile and before that a piece of text you would also like to have in the Makefile.  But what you have is already a valid Makefile; just glue the pieces together.  (The backslash after the first `pdflatex` should be removed, and other minor nits.)

Comment: This looks very promising. However I cannot make it work. I get an error : Makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.                       Could this originate from the "%" character on line 7 that in LaTeX starts a commented line?

Comment: No, it sounds like you didn't use tabs. They are required in Makefiles.

Comment: You are right, there must have been a problem with a tab. However I have now the error message below, and I do not know how to solve it.                           ! LaTeX Error: File `.tex' not found.

Answer (score 0):

Simple make file

```
all: main.o module.o                    \\ The dependencies of the target all   \
    gcc main.o module.o -o target_bin   \\ The action to make the target all    \
main.o: main.c module.h                 \\ The dependencies fo the target main.o    \
    gcc -I . -c main.c                  \\ The action to make the target main.o ,\
module.o: module.c module.h                                                     \
    gcc -I . -c module.c                \\ -I tells the compiler header file locations  \
clean:                                  \\ This target has no dependencies                      \
    rm -rf *.o                                                  \
    rm target_bin
```

Answering this question requires a relatively long explanation and a multi files for demonstration, I included a [HERE a link](https://github.com/amjadmajid/Makefile/blob/master/Makefile) to a github repo that answers this question in a compact (with enough details).